# best way to save chat messages in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

Is there a better way to log a chat other than writing to the db every time a message is received by the server. I'm considering saving the log after every chat session rather than per msg.

Comment: There could two approach to this.
- Save the log every x messages and keep it in memory until next save. Depending on your application x could be a small number like 5 or a bigger one like 50 if you're concerned with too frequent DB operations.
- Save the log every x seconds and keep it in memory until next save, if their was a new message received. The log could be a queue which empties everytime you save the log.

Comment: You could have a smarter saving approach by combining the 2 methods, ie saving messages as they arrive, and then save the few left when the conversation ends (users disconnect, or just when they stop chatting for a certain amount of time)

Comment: thanks your input helped the most.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install faye

var client = require("faye") ;
client.subscribe("/myChannel",    function(messageRecievedOnChannel){
  // each time a message is received in channel, 
  // log it + save to dB if needed. 
} ;
```

// read Faye manual for deeper understanding. 
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/faye

Comment: I think the OP is trying to figure out an other way of saving chat log other than just writing to DB everytime the server receives a message.
What your answer provides is just a way of doing this.